# NSInvalidArgumentException on SetUserId Unity iOS Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

In the [firebase documentation for SetUserId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/analytics/firebase-analytics#setuserid), it claims that `Setting userId to NULL or nullptr removes the user ID.` But when I do that, I get an exception that indicates that a null string isn't allowed.

My question:

1. Am I interpreting the documentation wrong? Is null not allowed?
2. If null isn't allowed (or if this is a bug with firebase) how do I get around it? How do I remove the user ID?

The line where I'm calling SetUserId:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserId(Authentication.IsAuthenticated ? Social.localUser.id : null);
```

Stacktrace:

```
2017-09-06 11:49:49.288 SunBlocks[10837:4796100] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: *** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x260ad0ef <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x347ecc77 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x260ad01d <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x26d1e78d <redacted> + 76
    4   SunBlocks                           0x016997bf _ZN8firebase9analytics9SetUserIdEPKc + 70
    5   SunBlocks                           0x00158a07 FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE_Firebase_Analytics_SetUserId_m547785349 + 30
    6   SunBlocks                           0x00158927 FirebaseAnalytics_SetUserId_m3682502317 + 148
    7   SunBlocks                           0x001065c5 FirebaseManager_OnAuthenticationPrepare_m4075942421 + 304
    8   SunBlocks                           0x002a28f1 EventHandler_1_Invoke_m768111117_gshared + 284
    9   SunBlocks                           0x000fe955 Authentication_raisePrepared_m1695901771 + 744
    10  SunBlocks                           0x000feb75 Authentication_OnAuthenticate_m3209094272 + 320
    11  SunBlocks                           0x0019ef6b Action_2_Invoke_m744924674_gshared + 284
    12  SunBlocks                           0x005ad617 GameCenterPlatform_AuthenticateCallbackWrapper_m2107931883 + 396
    13  SunBlocks                           0x00953da9 _Z62RuntimeInvoker_Void_t3468369357_Int32_t620045365_RuntimeObjectPFvvEPK10MethodInfoPvPS4_ + 48
    14  SunBlocks                           0x0168535b _ZN6il2cpp2vm7Runtime6InvokeEPK10MethodInfoPvPS5_PP15Il2CppException + 118
    15  SunBlocks                           0x010337d3 _Z23scripting_method_invoke18ScriptingMethodPtr18ScriptingObjectPtrR18ScriptingArgumentsP21ScriptingExceptionPtrb + 62
    16  SunBlocks                           0x010300c5 _ZN19ScriptingInvocation6InvokeEP21ScriptingExceptionPtrb + 86
    17  SunBlocks                           0x0122e0bd _Z24InvokeGameCenterCallbackPKcRK18ScriptingArguments + 144
    18  SunBlocks                           0x0122e18d _ZN10GameCenter26ExecuteGameCenterCallbacksEv + 118
    19  SunBlocks                           0x012272f9 _ZZL27InitializeModule_GameCentervEN51PostLateUpdateExecuteGameCenterCallbacksRegistrator7ForwardEv + 104
    20  SunBlocks                           0x00f15177 _Z10PlayerLoopv + 1710
    21  SunBlocks                           0x012355f7 _ZL19UnityPlayerLoopImplb + 32
    22  SunBlocks                           0x000ccaed UnityRepaint + 124
    23  SunBlocks                           0x000cca6d -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint] + 106
    24  SunBlocks                           0x000cc99d -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 120
    25  libMTLInterpose.dylib               0x042dcd2b -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 274
    26  QuartzCore                          0x2916fb67 <redacted> + 98
    27  QuartzCore                          0x2916f9cf <redacted> + 366
    28  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x2df0fc03 <redacted> + 90
    29  IOKit                               0x27027d0d IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x26062335 <redacted> + 132
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x2607282b <redacted> + 34
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x260727c7 <redacted> + 346
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x26070de9 <redacted> + 1608
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x25fbc6d1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x25fbc4e3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x2d9581a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
    37  UIKit                               0x2976e445 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    38  SunBlocks                           0x000c070b main + 250
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x34dbaaaf <redacted> + 2
)
2017-09-06 11:49:49.295 SunBlocks[10837:4796100] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. I'll report with the Firebase team. Thanks

Comment: @adbitx, can you link the issue/report here?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no external link to this bug. You may want to check out the next release if they fix the bug.

Comment: @adbitx I'd love to, unfortunately I'm unable to use it: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1892